# NavigationView, a way to uncheck previous selections?

Tags: android, layout, navigation, navigation-drawer

Yesterday I followed 2 tutorials to implement the `NavigationView` component for my Drawer instead of using a `ListView`. Since it's a lot smarter, I was wondering if there's an integrated way of keeping track which item is selected and when you select a new one, the old selection is removed?

Or should we implement that logic? Should I just keep 2 integers with the ID of the selected element, one `oldSelection` and one `newSelection` and uncheck the old one?

Suggestions are welcome, thank you!

The tutorials:

http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-navigation-drawer-view.html
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: are you using custom listview for display menu list?

Comment: As I explained in my question, I'm using a NavigationView, instead of a ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationView` does that for you , whenever u select a new item old item is removed and new is selected.

**Note:**

That this wont work for subMenu if u add any

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what's happening, my submenu is receiving this functionality from the NavigationView. So for now (probably they will fix that) we implement our own logic for sub menues.

Comment: @iBobb what logic did you use to uncheck the sub menus? I am stuck with a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "menuItem.setChecked(true);" in "setNavigationItemSelectedListener":

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        displayView(menuItem);

                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I've already done that, but thank you. The problem is I have a submenu.